# How would I solve this algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

So I've got a small question:

How do I solve this algebraically?

$x^2=x+6$

It's easy to see the answer but how would you solve it algebraically?

Comment: The thing to notice is that you have a quadratic equation. Can you solve these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach you can take that uses the *difference of squares* formula $$(u+v)(u-v)=u^2-v^2.$$ The following are equivalent (watch out for the clever step): $$x^2=x+6\\x^2-x=6\\x(x-1)=6\\\left(x-\frac12+\frac12\right)\left(x-\frac12-\frac12\right)=6$$ Letting $u=x-\frac12$ and $v=\frac12,$ we can rewrite this as: $$\left(x-\frac12\right)^2-\left(\frac12\right)^2=6\\\left(x-\frac12\right)^2-\frac14=6\\\left(x-\frac12\right)^2-\frac14-6=0\\\left(x-\frac12\right)^2-\frac{25}4=0\\\left(x-\frac12\right)^2-\left(\frac52\right)^2=0$$ Now, once again using the difference of squares formula gives us: $$\left(x-\frac12+\frac52\right)\left(x-\frac12-\frac52\right)=0\\(x+2)(x-3)=0$$ At that point, we conclude that $x+2=0$ or $x-3=0,$ so that $x=-2$ or $x=3.$

Comment: You are very welcome. A similar approach can always be used to solve equations that can be written in the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$ for some constants $a,b,c$ with $a\ne0.$ To begin with: $$ax^2+bx=-c\\x^2+\frac bax=-\frac ca\\x\left(x+\frac ba\right)=-\frac ca\\\left(x+\frac b{2a}-\frac b{2a}\right)\left(x+\frac b{2a}+\frac b{2a}\right)=-\frac ca$$ Continuing from there as above, we can rederive the quadratic formula on the fly, if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Quadratic equations can be solved in general by *completing the square*. In your example this goes like this:

$$6=x^2-x=\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}$$

Therefore the solutions are $$x=\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{6+\frac{1}{4}}.$$

Which evaluates to be $-2$ and $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Factor it:

$$x^2 - x - 6 = (x-3)(x+2) = 0 \to x = 3, -2.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
x^2&=x+6\\
x^2-x-6&=0\\
(x+2)(x-3)&=0
\end{align}
$$
So that $x+2=0\rightarrow x=-2$ and $x-3=0\rightarrow x=3$ are the only solutions.